# Python Start function at a given time: Using time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, scheduled-tasks

I'm using

```
a = datetime.now()
b = datetime(2018,4,26,00,7,00)
time.sleep((b-a).total_seconds())
```

to start my script at a given time, but I want to change it. Instead of using `datetime()` I want to use the module `time` because the year, month and day is irrelevant for me. I also want to ask for the start time via `input("Start time? ")`. I hope you can help me or maybe you have some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sched` module:

```
import sched, time

def my_scheduler(delay, func):
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(delay, 1, func)
    s.run()
```

Demo:

```
In [78]: def print_time(a='default'):
...          print("From print_time", time.time(), a)

In [77]: while True:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         delay = int(input("Enter the delay seconds:  "))
    ...:     except ValueError:
    ...:         print("Invalid input. Pleaes enter only digits!")
    ...:     else:
    ...:         my_scheduler(delay, print_time)
    ...:         break
    ...:     
Enter the delay seconds:  5
# after 5 seconds
From print_time 1525515514.618826 default
```